# Permission to retrieve server state data in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to run this query inside a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @Params = event_info 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@SPID, CURRENT_REQUEST_ID())
```

In order to catch the execution parameters of a stored procedure and print them if necessary (very useful for debugging). So for my `[dbo]` user is working wonderful, but the problem is when the `[AppUser]` (with limited permission) tries to execute the same stored procedure, this error appears:

> VIEW SERVER PERFORMANCE STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.

I have tried to create the user in master and assign to him:

1. `GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO [AppUser]`: did not work
2. `RANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [AppUser]`: not supported in Azure SQL
3. `ALTER SERVER ROLE ##MS_ServerStateReader## ADD MEMBER [AppUser]`: did not work.

I know that I can print the execution parameters by myself or log it to for example `dbo.traceTable`, in fact is what I was doing until I discovered this query that is much simple and easier to use.

So, is there any permission I can assign to `[AppUser]` in order to have permission to retirve data of the query?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Seems like I had to re-login after Role assignation of: `ALTER SERVER ROLE ##MS_ServerStateReader## ADD MEMBER [AppUser]` in order to take the changes.

Now my problem is that the initial query does not work properly with dapper, but this an another story...

Comment: To view server scoped DMVs, grant SELECT privilege to the `Login`, not the user. For viewing Database scoped DMVs grant SELECT privilege to the 'user'.

Comment: For the third command that you tried, you should execute it on `master` database. Also is the login name correctly given, check again.

Comment: Yes, I execute the third query in master DB, but seems like changes was not accepted until a re-login again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created login to Azure sql database with admin authentication created new login in master database using below code:

```
create login1 with password = '<password>'
```

I created a user with above login in my required database and assigned role to the user.

```
USE [database]
GO
CREATE USER <user> FOR LOGIN <login>
GO
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER <user>
GO
```

[image]

I login with the new user into the database and try to execute below code:

```
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @Params = event_info 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@SPID, CURRENT_REQUEST_ID())
```

I got below error:

[image]

I login into master database with admin authentication and added below role to the new login

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE ##MS_ServerStateReader##
  ADD MEMBER login1;  
GO
```

[image]

I query the same by connecting master database instead of my database with new login authentication it executed successfully without any error:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is was exactly what I have done and now is working... I might thinks is because when I added the user to this role I did not re-login with the User, and maybe this changes were not taken.